# Как получить размер вложенного массива

Tags: php

Решил сделать сайт по всем правилам используя json, реализовываю корзину пользователя, после всех манипуляций с json получаю в конечном итоге массив следующего вида

```php
$cart = 
[ 
    "id_0001" => [ 
        1 => [
            "color"    => "#000000",
            "size"     => 92,
            "quantity" => 3
        ], 
        2 => [
            "color"    => "#FFFFFF",
            "size"     => 92,
            "quantity" => 1
        ] 
    ],
    "id_0002" => [ 
        1 => [
            "color"    => "#23684B",
            "size"     => 92,
            "quantity" => 3
        ], 
        2 => [
            "color"    => "#5044C1",
            "size"     => 92,
            "quantity" => 1
        ] 
    ],
    "id_0003" => [ 
        1 => [
            "color"    => "#06130C",
            "size"     => 92,
            "quantity" => 3
        ], 
        2 => [
            "color"    => "#B83D96",
            "size"     => 92,
            "quantity" => 1
        ] 
    ]
];
```

далее я измеряю размер массива с помощью функции count() и использую полученный размер в цикле, следующий планируемый шаг - это попытка измерить под массив, чтобы перебрать и его во вложенном цикле, проблема заключается в том что функция count() размер под массива не определяет (выдаёт ноль), как быть? Может существует какая нибудь php функция которая способна определить размер под массива? Пример моего незаконченного кода

```php
$count_level_1 = count($cart); 
$count_level_1--; 

for ($i = 0; $i <= $count_level_1; $i++) {
    
    $count_level_2 = count($cart[$i]); //Получаю ноль

    for ($s = 0; $s <= $count_level_2; $s++) {
    
        //А этот цикл и вовсе не срабативает 
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Может я вообще не туда дую? Мне не понятно как такие задачи в принципе решаются, может он покажется вам глупым но я уже часа три ломаю голову и ни каких идей

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ноль получаете, потому что ключ используете `$i`, а у вас там какие-то `id_0003`.

Если вместо `for` будете использовать цикл `foreach($cart as $entry)` то `count($entry)` даст вам желаемый результат.

В целом если хотите получить общее число вложенных элементов, то логичным будет использование `array_reduce`, примерно так:

```
$result = array_reduce($data, $fn($acc, $v) =>  $acc + count($v), 0);
```

Либо что-то вроде такого

```
$result = array_sum(array_map('count', $data));
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое, я понял что очень невнимательно изучаю теорию, ключи под массивов у меня это айди товаров, благодаря вам я понял что мне надо переработать весь массив и айди я вставлю в самый последний под массив на ряду с характеристиками товаров (хотя изначально я продумывал другую логику), у вас очень большая репутация и пока есть шанс хочу этим воспользоваться, скажите пожалуйста правильно ли использовать трёх мерные массивы для хранения данных о заказываемых товарах?

Comment: @иосифмахарадзе нет универсального ответа правильно/неправильно. Каждая задача требует своего удобного решения.